# Unable to correcty call a void function in Java to output to the console

Tags: java

I have the following class written in the Employee.java script:

```
public class Employee {
    //***************************************************************
    //
    //  Developer:         Erin
    //
    //  Program #:         3
    //
    //  File Name:         Program3.java
    //
    //  Course:            Object-Oriented Programming - Java 
    //
    //  Due Date:          
    //
    //  Instructor:        Prof. Fred
    //
    //  Chapter:           3
    //
    //  Description:
    //  Program creates an Employee class that includes three (3) private instances:
        //   1) first name (String)
        //   2) last name (String)
    //   3) monthly salary (double)
    //  Program provides:
    //   a) a constructor that initializes instance variables
    //   b) set and get methods for each instance variable
    //   c) test app named EmployeeTest that demonstrates Employee class capabilities
    //   d) two (2) Employee objs, from which obj's yearly salary is displayed
    //   e) display of 20% raise for each Employee;s yearly salary
    //
    //***************************************************************
            private String _first_name;
            private String _last_name;
            private double _monthly_salary;

            public Employee(String first_name, String last_name, double monthlySalary)
            {
               setFirstName(first_name);
               setLastName(last_name);
                setMonthlySalary(monthlySalary);
            }
           
            public String getFirstName()
            {
                return _first_name;
            }
            public void setFirstName(String first_name)
            {
                _first_name = first_name;
            }
           
            public String getLastName()
            {
                return _last_name;
            }
           
            public void setLastName(String lastName)
            {
                _last_name =lastName;
            }
           
            public double getMonthlySalary()
            {
                return _monthly_salary;
            }
           
            public void setMonthlySalary(double monthlySalary)
            {
                if(monthlySalary < 0.0)
                {
                    monthlySalary = 0.0;
                }
               
                _monthly_salary = monthlySalary;
            }
    //***************************************************************
    //
    //  Method:       developerInfo
    // 
    //  Description:  The developer information method of the program
    //
    //  Parameters:   None
    //
    //  Returns:      N/A 
    //
    //**************************************************************
    public void developerInfo()
    {
       System.out.println("Name:    Erin");
       System.out.println("Course:  Object-Oriented Programming");
       System.out.println("Program: Three \n");
    }
}
```

With the corresponding test class written in a separate script called EmployeeTest.java:

```
public class EmployeeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        **developerInfo();**
        
        Employee employee1 = new Employee("John", "Doe", 2875.00);
        Employee employee2 = new Employee("Jane", "Doe", 3150.00);

        System.out.printf("%s %n", "Before 20% raise:");
        System.out.printf( "Employee 1: %s %s; Yearly Salary: $%.2f\n",
                employee1.getFirstName(), employee1.getLastName(),
                12 * employee1.getMonthlySalary() );
        System.out.printf( "Employee 2: %s %s; Yearly Salary: $%.2f\n",
                employee2.getFirstName(), employee2.getLastName(),
                12 * employee2.getMonthlySalary() );
        
        employee1.setMonthlySalary(employee1.getMonthlySalary() * 1.2);
        employee2.setMonthlySalary(employee2.getMonthlySalary() * 1.2);

        System.out.printf("%s %n", "After 20% raise:");
        System.out.printf( "Employee 1: %s %s; Yearly Salary: $%.2f\n",
                employee1.getFirstName(), employee1.getLastName(),
                12 * employee1.getMonthlySalary() );
        System.out.printf( "Employee 2: %s %s; Yearly Salary: $%.2f\n",
                employee2.getFirstName(), employee2.getLastName(),
                12 * employee2.getMonthlySalary() );
        
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to call the developerInfo function in order get that to print to the console. Expected output is:

```
Name: Erin
Course: Object-Oriented Programming
Program: Three

Before 20% raise: 
Employee 1: John Doe; Yearly Salary: $34500.00
Employee 2: Jane Doe; Yearly Salary: $37800.00
After 20% raise: 
Employee 1: John Doe; Yearly Salary: $41400.00
Employee 2: Jane Doe; Yearly Salary: $45360.00
```

Any insight would be so appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Make the method static `static public void developerInfo() {...` and call it like `Employee.developerInfo();`

Comment: Why don't you use the employee instances to call #developerInfo(). Something like employee1.developerInfo() ??

Comment: Java naming conventions have Classes in CamelCase starting with an upper case letter; methods and variables are also in camelCase starting with a lower case letters. They do not have underscores. They do not begin with an underscore. Following these conventions makes the programs easier to read by java programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists two possibilites. First you can make the method static:

```java
public static void developerInfo() {
    System.out.println("Name:    Erin");
    System.out.println("Course:  Object-Oriented Programming");
    System.out.println("Program: Three \n");
}
```

Then you can call the method with `Employee.developerInfo()`. Second you can use an instance of the `Employee` class and you can call the method:

```java
employee1.developerInfo();
```

Since it is not directly related to an employee, I would take the first option or outsource the method.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I didn't know you could make the method static. That was an easy fix, thanks again! @flaxel